# "List does not exist..." while adding webpart on home page

Tags: list, web-part

I create a very simple list and then try to add a webpart of newly created list to home page of my site. It gives me the strange error of:

```
List does not exist.

The page that you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.
```

I'm able to add this list to other pages of my site.

I can see list items when I check list from 'all site content'.

I've added some lists to my home page before but now I can not.

'logs' doesn't give me any thing else. Just the same error message.

Any ideas may be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the fields displayed in the selected view are working/provisioned correctly.

I once had this problem due to a field that was not working correctly. Deleted the field from the list and it worked again.

Comment: Actually I've this problem with the default instance of  custom list with no changes. It has just a title (which is single line of text) and a body (which is multiple lines of text). That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are creating the list at the same level as your home page first as a test if you are not already. Lists on sub-sites could have permission issues to jump over as well.

Can you still add the older items you have on the home page? Just try to add one of the old web/app parts in a blank space and see if you have success. That would at least tell you that it isn't your list but something to do with the home page. Also, was the home page migrated? Is it classic or modern?